# Is there a way to find the sum of the last n and first n elements in a 2D array using only NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Lets say that **n** is a variable and I use a simple matrix example.

```
import numpy as np

n = 2

matrix = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
                   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

desired_output = np.array([[nan, nan, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, nan, nan], 
                           [nan, nan, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, nan, nan]])
```

So desired_output[i] = sum of elements in the interval **matrix[i - n, i + n]** both inclusive.
Is there a way to do this using NumPy and without python iteration? The numbers in the array can be arbitrary.

Comment: for clarity show your calculation, even if it uses iteration,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of my absolute favorite things to be added to numpy in 1.20: `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
                   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
n = 2
```

First, apply the sliding window view:

```
window_size = 2 * n + 1
arr = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(matrix, window_size, axis=1)
```

Then sum it on the last axis:

```
arr = arr.sum(axis=2)
```

This gives you:

```
>>> arr
array([[10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35],
       [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35]])
```

To the best of my knowledge there's no integer NaN in numpy so your integer/nan output is impossible. If you want floats you can pad easily with nans though:

```
arr_padded = np.full((arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1] + 2 * n), np.nan)
arr_padded[:, n:-1 * n] = arr

>>> arr_padded
array([[nan, nan, 10., 15., 20., 25., 30., 35., nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, 10., 15., 20., 25., 30., 35., nan, nan]])
```